# Mongoose stops responding after unspecified period of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose

I have been tearing my hair out over this problem pretty much since I began developing my project (12 months ago!), always assuming I would find an answer before I was ready to release... unfortunately, that was not the case!

Basically, I have a fairly straightforward node.js server running on Azure connecting to a MongoLab (now MLab) database using mongoose.

The connection code looks like this:

```
// Connect to DB
//mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect(envConfig.app.db, {
    server: {
        auto_reconnect: true,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            socketTimeoutMS : 30000,
        }
    },
    replset: {
        auto_reconnect: true,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 1,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            socketTimeoutMS : 30000,
        }
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) winstonLogger.error(err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function () {
    console.log('Connecting to MongoDB...');
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connection opened!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Error in MongoDb connection: ' + err.stack);
    winstonLogger.error(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    winstonLogger.error('MongoDB disconnected!');
    mongoose.connect(envConfig.app.db, {
        server: {
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
                socketTimeoutMS : 30000,
            }
        },
        replset: {
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
                socketTimeoutMS : 30000,
            }
        }
    });
});
mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('close', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB closed');
});
```

All of the extra timeout options, etc you see are part of my attempts to fix this problem (to no avail).

Here is a typical request:

```
AccessToken.findOne({ token: token })
            .maxTime(10000)
            .exec(function (err, accessToken) {
                // If I even got to here I would be happy
                if (err) return done(err);
                // If I could consistently get to here, my project would be finished and I would enjoy being alive again
            });
```

So, when I boot up my server everything works great. And it keeps working great... sometimes for days, sometimes hours, sometimes minutes. At some point, however, a request will hit this code and it will just... hang. No timeouts, no errors. Just nada. I have not found any evidence in any logs that show any evidence of what's happening. My express logger finally gives up and I get something like:

```
POST /api/auth/verify - - ms - -
```

So at this point, my only option is to restart the server, as I cannot get a db request to complete (or timeout, or show an error) for love nor money.

I have scoured the Internet for a year hoping for a solution, but everything I have tried has resulted in... nothing... the same result. I even tried running my own replica set on Azure instead of using MongoLab. Same problem. My only thinking is that it's an Azure problem with no apparent solution, but I'm really not keen on finding another host. That being said, I don't understand why the Mongoose requests don't timeout or show any error, even when I have set a maxTime...

Here's some info from MongoLab on what I thought might be the problem:
http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#known-issues,
but as you can see, I have tried everything they suggest, and much more, with no success.

I am truly at a loss, and the whole situation is simultaneously brain-numbing, heartbreaking and unbelievably infuriating.

If anyone out there has ANY ideas at all, I will love you forever...

Thank you in advance!

-Luke

Comment: Can you verify here if it is the application that stops doing anything or whether it is the server. The basic test is therefore to try and connect to the server after the point that the application seems to not be doing anything. I would also be looking at the server logs for things like the number of connections growing and/or any socket timeout messages.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So everything else on the server keeps running fine, it's just any mongoose request that doesn't respond. How could I log any socket timeout messages?

Comment: I have made a little progress. If I explicitly set the socket timeout to 30secs like I have done here, the hanging seems to happen after 30 seconds. Seems reasonably clear then... but why doesn't it just create a new socket connection for a new request, and why can't I get it to give me any errors?

Comment: Well no database client ever just creates a new socket for every request, well not the good ones anyway. Most implementations use a connection pool, and if new operations need a connection where none is available then those just queue up until one becomes available. So either operations are taking a really long time or simply are not notifying completion and closing cursors. Hard to tell without the code, but exactly why you should be looking at the server logs for the number of active connections.

Comment: Should socketTimeout be forcing the issue though? Thanks for the advice, anyway. I just rebooted the db and this is what mongo has to say: 
    "connections": {
        "current": 11,
        "available": 14989,
        "totalCreated": 43
    }
...Which seems to stay pretty stable when I try and make new requests. No failures reported, either. Is there something else in particular I should be looking for in Mongo? If there's code I can give you that would help, no problem, but theres really nothing more to it than what I posted above!

Comment: Well I scoured as many logs as I could find, and still no evidence of what the hell is happening. Seems to me the likeliest culprit is Mongoose and that it's swallowing whatever information it might have on what's going on. I just explicitly set socketTimeoutMS to 0, which is something I've not tried before (because I think that's the default in Mongoose?). This means that, like before, I can use my app fine for now, but it will probably stop working again after a few hours or days. I'll report back with how long it takes and if there is any more information I can gather about it...

Comment: Sigh, it stopped working during the night. No errors in the logs, it just hangs on every request again, so I will have to restart the server... :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a great deal like an issue I had for months with the same setup (NodeJs on Azure, Mongoose, MongoLab replica set). It was "simultaneously brain-numbing, heartbreaking and unbelievably infuriating", for sure. I finally solved it a few months ago after way too many hours of frustration...

I found that it was triggered by replica set failovers. This was verified by using a test server on Azure and test replica set on MongoLab and manually triggering failovers on Mongolab (I could not repro by running the NodeJs server and MongoDB instance locally, since the problem has something to do with connection times).

The high availability checks that are supposed to help Mongoose to connect to the secondary after a failover weren't running correctly. Due to some kind of race condition, if the server takes a while to boot up after initializing the Mongoose connection, the callback to start the checks fails in mongodb-core.

What I ended up doing is **moving the Mongoose connection as late into the server startup process as possible**. It used to be before a pretty large file minification task, which was likely the problem.

Hope this helps!

My Mongoose settings:

```
// Options
mongooseOptions.replset = {
  ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
  haInterval: 5000, // Run every 5 seconds
  socketOptions : {
    ... // nothing special here
  }
}

mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri, mongooseOptions);

// Make sure the high availability checks are occuring
// Should see "replset ha start" "replset ha end" pairs every 5 secs
// Well, hopefully.
if (mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset) {
  mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset.on('ha', function(type, data) {
    console.log('replset ha ' + type);
  })
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion. I don't really have anything that happens on startup other than the db connection, but I will give your settings a go, I didn't know about the ha option... although it looks like it's supposed to be on by default? https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#high-availability-on-by-default ... regardless I have tried it just now and I get 'replset ha start' on startup, but that's it, even though haInterval is set to 5000... any idea why that might be?

Comment: Ohh I forced a failover on MLab, and it caused the connections to start hanging, that's very interesting... Not good, of course, but we might be onto something here!

Comment: I don't want to get ahead of myself, but things are looking really good! I made a few tweaks and now I'm getting the replset ha start/end messages. Furthermore, if I trigger a failover, it automatically reconnects, with a message and everything! All I can do now is leave it up and hope for the best, but I'm very excited!! Will report back...

Comment: OK, so basically, it looks like it works (and reconnects in the event of a failover) when I can get it to respond to the ha checks. It does this on a local server, but not on Azure, except that it did once, but after restarting for maintenance it was no longer. To reiterate: when I get ha start ha end messages, it works, which it does on a local server... but on Azure I don't get these messages :(

Comment: I increased the haInterval to 10 seconds and now I can get it to mostly work. The above comment still stands, but I've got a good enough system for now that I can keep restarting the server until I can get it to maintain a consistent connection. All being well this is the end of this sorry story! Still not sure what the problem is/was, but hopefully my server will work now and that's all that really matters I suppose. Thank you again for your help, @KatherineTung, you are marvellous!

Comment: @LukeLarsen Wonderful to hear it's (mostly) working! :D Once I moved the Mongoose connection to the bottom I didn't have unreliable haIntervals anymore (unless your server startup times vary enough that only *sometimes* it runs into the race condition), so I'm not sure what's going on with your setup unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so I haven't had the issue for a while now. I made a lot of small changes to the connection settings, but I think what had the biggest impact was either explicitly setting the ha (high availability) and haInterval replset options, or possibly moving the connection code to the very end of my app.js.

Here's what the final connection code looked like:

```
// Connect to DB
var connectionOptions = {
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            connectTimeoutMS: 300000, // 5 minutes
            keepAlive: 120
        },
        ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
        haInterval: 10000, // Run every 10 seconds
    }
};
//mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect(envConfig.app.db, connectionOptions, function (err) {
    if (err) winstonLogger.error(err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function () {
    console.log('Connecting to MongoDB...');
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB connection opened!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    winstonLogger.error(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    winstonLogger.error('MongoDB disconnected!');
    mongoose.connect(envConfig.app.db, connectionOptions, function (err) {
        if (err) winstonLogger.error(err);
    });
});
mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB reconnected!');
});
mongoose.connection.on('close', function () {
    winstonLogger.error('MongoDB closed');
});
if (mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset) {
    mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset.on('ha', function(type, data) {
        console.log('replset ha ' + type);
    });
    mongoose.connection.db.serverConfig.s.replset.on('timeout', function () {
        winstonLogger.error('MongoDB timeout');
    });
}
```

I also turned on the AlwaysOn option for the Azure WebApp (which didn't seem to have much effect, but I'm not switching it off now that it's working!).

It does seem like the issue had something to do with not reconnecting after a failover, but I couldn't say with 100% certainty.

Hopefully this will help someone else out who runs into the same problem... and hopefully I haven't jumped the gun only to have it stop working again in a few days (I'll be back if that happens!).

Thanks to everyone who provided a suggestion, I am ETERNALLY grateful :)

Comment: I have run into the same situation, so you think make the haInterval longer will resolve the issue(default is 2000) and you didn't face this issue anymore.

Comment: FYI, please try to upgrade the mongoose, it seems they fail to reconnect when failover. (previous version i used is 4.6.5 and tried 4.7.5) Let's see if the new version will resolve the problem.

Also the default haInterval is 10000, so no need to amend.

Comment: and here in 2020 I am facing the same issue, this time with serverless

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Did you solved it? I am also stuck at the same and tried lot but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I suggest that you could ping the mongodb on Mlab to make sure whether running out of mongo connections when your webapp has been hanging.

I think you could try to add the connection pool option for mongoose connections, as @BlakesSeven said. Please see the section `Connection pools` of [Mongoose guide topic `Connections`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to configure the pool size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the following connection settings: 
"replset": {
            "poolSize": 10,
            "socketOptions": {
                "noDelay": true,
                "connectTimeoutMS": 30000,
                "keepAlive": 1,
                "socketTimeoutMS": 0
            }
        }
Things were going well... for about 10 hours before it stopped working again.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think I can safely say that there's no problem with the database connection on MLab (new connections work fine when the app is hanging, and the app itself just needs to be restarted), and the detailed mongo error logs don't show any signs of failed connections. Surely by process of elimination this suggests the problem is with Mongoose? I would open a bug report with them if I could just figure out exactly what it is that's going wrong... The thing that really irks me is why isn't there an error thrown after the maxTime passes for a query?

Comment: @LukeLarsen Did you enable the `Always On` option for node.js server if using WebApp? Azure unload the server if it is idle for the standard 20 minute timeout. For keeping the server alive, you can enable the `Always On` option for webapp or ping the server with an interval.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was a setting - totally bums me out that I never noticed it. It was not enabled, but I have made the switch, I will report back on whether it makes a difference...